# Docker 0.9 - /etc/sysctl.conf not working

Tags: image, docker, sysctl

I set `net.core.somaxconn = 65535` in **/etc/sysctl.conf** inside an Ubuntu image.

But the `net.core.somaxconn` turns to **128** in the container using command `sysctl -a | grep net.core.somaxconn`.

After I execute `sysctl -p`, it turns to **65535**.

Why doesn't **/etc/sysctl.conf** work when running a container (Docker 0.9) ？

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the case because Docker does not run `sysctl` for you. I don't know how you start your container, but if you do something like `docker run -i -t image /bin/bash` it only starts bash. There is no upstart kicked of or anything, so if you decide running `sysctl` is important, you need to do that yourself.

For development purposes, you can use

```
docker run -i -t image sysctl -p && /bin/bash
```

For production use, you might want to take a look at [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) or at my [blog](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/) on that.

Comment: I add `sysctl -p;` before previous ENTRYPOINT

Comment: please add your Dockerfile, because your comment got lost in translation :)